# Is there a meaning to the test instruction if it isnt followed by a conditional jump?

Tags: assembly, x86

Pasting a snippet of code I found inside a malware sample.

```
0040F695    push ecx                    
0040F696    lea ecx,dword ptr ss:[esp+8]
0040F69A    sub ecx,1000                
0040F6A0    sub eax,1000                
0040F6A5    test dword ptr ds:[ecx],eax 
0040F6A7    cmp eax,1000                
0040F6AC    jae sample.40F69A           
0040F6AE    sub ecx,eax                 
0040F6B0    mov eax,esp                 
0040F6B2    test dword ptr ds:[ecx],eax 
0040F6B4    mov esp,ecx                 
0040F6B6    mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[eax]  
0040F6B8    mov eax,dword ptr ds:[eax+4]
0040F6BB    push eax                    
0040F6BC    ret
```

I am not sure what the test instruction achieves here. I am used to seeing a conditional jump right after it. But here there is a test, cmp and then a conditional jump and also a test followed by no jumps. Would it make any difference if the test instructions were omitted?

Comment: It seems like a junk instruction here. The result of the first `test` is not used because of a `cmp` right after it, but there is still a (small) chance that the result of the second `test` is actually used later on after `ret` - it affected flags whch were not overwritten afterwards. The first `test` is a junk instruction and so is the second most likely.

Comment: @bart1e Can this sort of instruction be used to put off decompilers?

Comment: Possibly, but I think that these esp manipulations confuse decompilers even more.